# Uploading apps to other stores than google play

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I was searching for alternatives because I want other stores than google play to get more exposure, and I found one called Aptoide, the question is how are users uploading apps like Facebook, Instagram etc... to theses types of stores ? I mean they aren't even the real owners of these apps, and they get million of downloads, I am really confused, can somebody explain please ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

When you download an app, you are just downloading an APK, an install file for the app. There are lots of ways to get the file, with the easiest being with an APK backup app such as [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayan.nurav.apkshare&hl=en&rdid=com.kayan.nurav.apkshare).